# Programmatically update products

Tags: commerce, 9

I am building a site with Drupal 9 and Drupal Commerce 2 (Drupal Commerce Kickstart).

The site is complete and I have already entered all the products via Feed (there are over a million). Now I'm looking for a way to periodically update the products automatically (prices, availability, etc.)

In an old site that I had made and which was developed with Drupal 7 and did not use Drupal Commerce, it was very easy to update the nodes (products) through some scripts I had made, while in this case it is not that simple.

I thought about updating with Feed, but it's really too slow, in fact I can't update more than 20/30 products in each cron cycle; I therefore need to use a customized and faster solution. The first feed upload also took a long time.

I tried to create a php script that calls the entity of the nodes I want to modify like I did with the old site, but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried to follow [this guide for Drupal 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874672/how-to-create-products-programmatically-in-drupal-8-commerce/56225927#56225927), but I'm probably wrong to use some function or something is changed for Drupal 9.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Using cron to execute feeds is pretty slow, so what about executing feeds with drush?

Here is a simple drush script I use to import feeds.

Execute it like this:

`drush php-script import_feeds.php`

Note that you need to use the Drupal id of each feed to import by ID.

**import_feeds.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Import feeds.
 */

import_everything_in_order();
    
/**
 * Import all feeds in order of dependencies.
 */
function import_everything_in_order(): void {
  $id_user = 1;
  $id_media_image = 7;
  $id_page = 3;

  $feeds_to_import = [
    $id_user,
    $id_media_image,
    $id_page,
  ];
  foreach ($feeds_to_import as $feed_to_import) {
    unlock_and_import($feed_to_import);
  }
}

/**
 * Unlock a feed and then import it.
 *
 * This ensures that dependency import doesn't fail
 * due to locked feeds.
 */
function unlock_and_import(int $feed_id): void {
  exec("drush feeds:unlock $feed_id -y");
  exec("drush feeds:import $feed_id -y");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried drush feeds as you suggested, but the update speed of the feeds doesn't change. It is certainly a more reliable solution than using the UI, but from some initial tests it does not solve the problem of execution speed. I have to update thousands of products daily and this slowness is really a problem. @Patrick